# Gaming console (XBox) through wall in another room

Tags: controllers, xbox-one, hardware

I'm looking to wall mount the TV in my lounge, which would give it a nice, clean look. However, I've got an XBox one and want to get an XBox Series X in the future. My partner wants to avoid having an entertainment unit/cabinet for housing these.

There is a cupboard on the other side of the wall behind the TV. I was thinking of getting an electrician to put some cable ducting through the wall so I can put the consoles in the cupboard and run HDMI cables through to the TV.

Will the controllers work through the wall? Are there any other issues with this approach?

Comment: This isn't guaranteed to be a solution for the Series X, since the related hardware will likely be different between Xbox One, but maybe try testing this with your Xbox One now - go into the other room, and see if the controller disconnects.  If it doesn't, have someone watch the TV to see if the controls respond.  You will likely be increasing the likely hood that your controller will disconnect randomly though should this work.  It just doesn't seem like a good idea.

Comment: @TimmyJim While it is unreleased, the question is still valid without the Series X being included.  Also, while it's possible for it to change by release, they've claimed Xbox One controllers will work with the new system (and the new controllers will work with the old system).

Comment: You could also run a USB extension through the wall into a wall plate and get a nice long cable if the wall has metal studs or other obstructions. It's a pain, but it would be a lot less frustrating than unreliable controllers. I believe they make plates with HDMI and multiple USBs, so you wouldn't need something separate for the TV and it would be nice and tidy for your partner.

Comment: The other potential option is to get a bluetooth receiver for the controllers to connect to, which would connect to USB extension cables.  If there's nothing in the wall (likely for an interior wall), you could hollow it out behind the TV - the distance between studs should be around 12-16 inches.  This will probably also work for the Series X as well, although the drives may be somewhat difficult to access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this would depend heavily on the content of the wall, but in my experience, *yes, it will work*. This is all anecdotal, but i have a very tiny house so it was easy to test:

My XB1 controllers all work through a wall (or multiple walls) made of regular wood and drywall. Some include wiring, insulation, and aluminum siding (tested from the porch).

Distance from the xbox seems to be the limiting factor in my testing.

However, if a wall contains anything metallic (pipes, metal sheeting, maybe even insulation with metallic backing), you could definitely see issues or a complete disconnect. I was personally surprised the siding didn't affect anything, but I can confirm I stood in my driveway and was able to have a clear voice chat via headphones, at about 20ft away from console.

The only way I could get mine to disconnect personally was to put a wall that contained a lot of plumbing between myself and the console, at about 25ft distance, and it dropped after a few seconds of waving it around.